# Iterating over an array

Tags: javascript

```
{title:'Alan', hasChild:true},
{title:'Alice', hasDetail:true},
{title:'Amos'},
{title:'Alonzo'},
{title:'Brad'},
{title:'Brent'},    
{title:'Billy'},    
{title:'Brenda'},   
{title:'Callie'},
{title:'Cassie'},   
{title:'Chris'},
```

How to iterate over an array and find out the index and first character of each element.

Comment: @SLaks: Actually, it is, even though the leading `[` and trailing `]` have been omitted. More specifically, it's an array where each element is an inline object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating is easy:

```
for (var i = 0; i < yourArrayName.length; i++) {
    yourArrayName[i].title.charAt(0) // This is the first letter.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (var i = 0, len = ary.length; i < len; i++) {   
        document.write("index:" + i + " -- first character: " + ary[i].title.charAt(0));
    }
```

Comment: leaking i into global scope. Please don't do that.

Comment: Always declare variables before use. `for ( var i = 0;...`

Comment: it would according to this: http://taitems.github.com/Front-End-Development-Guidelines/

Comment: @tylermwashburn it has non-zero inpact on performance. It's a good thing to get used to in larger loops.

Comment: @Raynos Really? It's just storing the property in a different place. How would that help?

Comment: @tylermwashburn `i < foo.length` is a condition that gets evaluated at the end of the loop. `i < len` is a condition that does not involve the property look up on `foo.length`. The latter gets `foo.length` once rather then `foo.length` times. It's a micro optimisation but still a good habit.

Comment: @Raynos Well the loop has to get len too.

Comment: @tylermwashburn but the loop had to get both `foo` and `foo.length` before. This is extra (tiny) lookup. A better example would be : `for (var i = 0, len = $(this).length; i < len; i++)` vs `for (var i = 0; i < $(this).length; i++)`. You can see why calling `$(this)` once is cheaper then calling it n times.

Comment: @Raynos OH. Ok. I get what you're saying.

Comment: @Raynos: which one do you recommend me to use, the first one or second one in your comment.

Answer (score 1):

You can just loop over it like a normal array, I'm pretty sure:

```
for (var i = 0; i < your_array.length; i++) {
  foo(your_array[i].title[0]);
}
```

Comment: Using an index on a string like that is bad practice.

Comment: @tyler, why do you say that? I'm not a JS person myself, so it might be something with the language, but for almost all the other languages I've encountered, it worked.

Comment: It works, but it could conflict if the string had a 0 property (which would have to go through String.prototype, and would be weird, but it still stands.)

Comment: Now is that practical in an everyday scenario? I've never had a problem with it, but if I edit my answer, it'll be another duplicate.

Comment: @tylermwashburn try setting property `"0"` on a string. It won't break. You can't overwrite the numeric indices of a string. (In chrome & ff using `string[i]` is safe.

Comment: @Raynos Hmm.. Didn't know that. I'm pretty sure I saw it on a list of bad practices somewhere, but apparently it's good.

Comment: @tylermwashburn probably breaks in IE6 or something.

Comment: @Raynos But it probably doesn't have a `.charAt` method either. xD

Comment: Don't question Microsoft's browser features!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use ES5 you can have more fun!

```
array.map(function(val) {
    return val.title;
}).forEach(function(title, index) {
    console.log("First character", title[0], "at index", index);
})
```

this will break in ES3 browsers.

Comment: @JohnCooper `val` is every object in your array.So it would be `{ "title": ... }`